# Is there a way to determine if a parameter is a literal string?

Tags: c++, string, literals, type-traits

My question is:

**Is there a way to determine whether a parameter is a literal string or not?**

```
template<class T>
bool IsLiteral(T arg)
{
    // How to implement?
}
```

or

```
template<class T>
struct IsLiteral { enum { value = ??? }; };
```

So that we can write the following code:

```
char* p = "Hello";

assert(IsLiteral(p)); // fail.
assert(IsLiteral("Hello")); // never fail.
assert(IsLiteral<decltype("Hello")>::value); // never fail.
```

Comment: I suppose you could make it fail when it doesn't satisfy `const char *&&`, but that wouldn't only succeed for literals. I have no idea why you want this functionality.

Comment: @Shafik, literal strings are related to C.

Comment: @xmllmx literal strings are related to C, but templates aren't.

Comment: Another possible duplicate: [Can a compilation error be forced if a string argument is not a string literal?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18563585/420683)

Comment: @DyP I did not even think to look ... my those macros are ugly ... if I think about it [user define literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) could be a nice alternative depending on the use case.

Comment: @chris: Knowing if something was a string literal would be very useful. You would then be able to make an encapsulating `string_ref` like class for which you could guarantee that the source string would never change and would always be valid.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, Fair enough :)

Comment: Note that `char* p = "Hello";` should not compile on newer compilers since `"Hello"` is a `char const *` and thus it can't be assigned to a `char *` without a `const_cast<char *>()`.

Answer (score 0):

"String Literal" is a source code term. Once the code is compiled it assigns/loads it into a memory location. The code using its value doesn't care or know if it was created at runtime or compiled time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to detect string literals. What can be detected is that argument is a fixed size array of `char const`:

```
template <std::size_t N>
bool IsLiteral(char const (&)[N]) {
    return true;
}
template <std::size_t N>
bool IsLiteral(char (&)[N]) {
    return false;
}
template <typename T>
bool IsLiteral(T) {
    return false;
}
```

I don't think you can distinguish between these two uses, however:

```
char const array[] = { 'a' };
IsLiteral(array);
IsLiteral("foo");
```

Comment: I knew that I've [seen this before...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18563696/420683) ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to determine whether a parameter is a literal string or not?

I don't think so, a string literal is prepocessing token and will be  turned into an array of const char, so you won't be able to distinguish if such as array came from a string literal or not. If we look at the C++ draft standard section `2.14.5` *String literals* paragraph *8* says:

> **Ordinary string literals** and UTF-8 string literals are also referred to as narrow string literals. A narrow string literal **has type “array of n const char”**, where n is the size of the string as defined below, and has static storage duration.