# Is it possible to overload a function that can tell a fixed array from a pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, c++11

**Motivation:**

Almost for fun, I am trying to write a function overload that can tell apart whether the argument is a fixed-size array or a pointer.

```
double const  d[] = {1.,2.,3.};
double a;
double const* p = &a;
f(d); // call array version
f(p); // call pointer version
```

I find this particularly difficult because of the well known fact that arrays decay to pointer sooner than later. A naive approach would be to write

```
void f(double const* c){...}
template<size_t N> void f(double const(&a)[N]){...}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Because in the best case the compiler determines the array call `f(d)` above to be ambiguous.

**Partial solution:**

I tried many things and the closest I could get was the following concrete code. Note also that, in this example code I use `char` instead of `double`, but it is very similar at the end.

First, I have to use SFINAE to disable conversions (from array ref to ptr) in the pointer version of the function. Second I had to overload for all possible arrays sizes (manually).

[compilable code]

```
#include<type_traits> // for enable_if (use boost enable_if in C++98)
#include<iostream>
template<class Char, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Char, char>::value>::type>
void f(Char const* dptr){std::cout << "ptr" << std::endl;} // preferred it seems

void f(char const (&darr)[0] ){std::cout << "const arr" << std::endl;}
void f(char const (&darr)[1] ){std::cout << "const arr" << std::endl;}
void f(char const (&darr)[2] ){std::cout << "const arr" << std::endl;}
void f(char const (&darr)[3] ){std::cout << "const arr" << std::endl;}
void f(char const (&darr)[4] ){std::cout << "const arr" << std::endl;}
void f(char const (&darr)[5] ){std::cout << "const arr" << std::endl;}
void f(char const (&darr)[6] ){std::cout << "const arr" << std::endl;} // this is the one called in this particular example
// ad infinitum ...

int main(){     
    f("hello"); // print ptr, ok because this is the fixed size array
    f(std::string("hello").c_str()); // print arr, ok because `c_str()` is a pointer
}
```

This works, but the problem is that I have to repeat the function for all possible values of `N` and using `template<size_t N>` gets me back to square zero, because with the template parameter the two calls get back to equal footing.
In other words, `template<size_t N> void f(char const(&a)[N]){std::cout << "const arr" << std::endl;}` doesn't help.

**Is there any way to generalize the second overload without falling back to an ambiguous call? or is there some other approach?**

A C++ or C++1XYZ answer is also welcome.

Two details: 1) I used `clang` for the experiments above, 2) the actual `f` will end up being an `operator<<`, I think know if that will matter for the solution.

---

**Summary of solutions** (based on other people's below) and adapted to a the concrete type `char` of the example. Both seem to depend on making the `char const*` pointer less obvious for the compiler:

1. One *weird* (portable?), (from the comment of @dyp.) Adding a reference qualifier to the pointer version:

```
    template<class Char, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Char, char>::value>::type>
    void f(Char const* const& dptr){std::cout << "ptr" << std::endl;}
    
    template<size_t N>
    void f(char const (&darr)[N] ){std::cout << "const arr" << std::endl;}
```

2. One elegant (special case from @user657267)

```
    template<class CharConstPtr, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<CharConstPtr, char const*>::value>::type>
    void f(CharConstPtr dptr){std::cout << "ptr" << std::endl;}
    
    template<size_t N>
    void f(char const (&darr)[N] ){std::cout << "const arr" << std::endl;}
```

Comment: How about using `std::array` instead of raw arrays?

Comment: @user657267, thanks, I just want a solution not involving changing the code in the main function. The reason, if you want to know is that I want to tell hard coded text (`"hello"`) from text resulting from a pointer.

Comment: There's a weird work-around: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/37214a2859f7e78d A more obvious solution is to use tag dispatch.

Comment: Can you overload based on constness instead?

Comment: @Thomas, I tried that in the `main` code both are `const` so I can't exploit that, I think

Comment: @dyp, thanks your worked too, although it is really weird why.

Comment: Taking the pointer by const reference blocks array-to-pointer decay during template argument deduction.

Comment: @T.C. , ...only if there is a template deduction also involved, simply writing `void f(char const* const& dptr){std::cout << "ptr" << std::endl;}` doesn't solve the issue. In my `clang++` at least.

Comment: @alfC I did say "during template argument deduction" :)

Comment: @T.C., sorry it was late.

Comment: One problem with #2, that #1 doesn't have is that it's "function not found" for a non-const pointer. Which means you'd eventually run into writing something like `void g(char * p) { f(const_cast<const char *>(p)); }`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This seems to work for me

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer<T>::value>
foo(T) { std::cout << "pointer\n"; }

template<typename T, std::size_t sz>
void foo(T(&)[sz]) { std::cout << "array\n"; }

int main()
{
  char const* c;
  foo(c);
  foo("hello");
}
```

Bonus `std::experimental::type_traits`:

```
using std::experimental::is_pointer_v;
std::enable_if_t<is_pointer_v<T>>
```

---

Your comment made me try something even simpler

```
template<typename T> void foo(T) { std::cout << "pointer\n"; }
template<typename T, unsigned sz> void foo(T(&)[sz]) { std::cout << "array\n"; }
```

Of course the problem here is that `foo` is now callable for any type, depends on how lax you want your parameter checking to be.

---

One other way is to (ab)use rvalue references

```
void foo(char const*&) { std::cout << "pointer\n"; }
void foo(char const*&&) { std::cout << "array\n"; }
```

Obviously it's not foolproof.

Comment: Great, you got it, as soon as one removes the pointer explicitly from the argument type the decay doesn't happen. I posted in the question the solution in the style of my original code (for `char` types in particular.)

Comment: Comment to your edit: actually that is not a problem, see my summary of solutions above. (I put the summary to give the concrete case of a `char`-only based overload)

Comment: N.B. things in `std::experimental` are not part of "c++1z" or any other draft/future standard, they're in a separate namespace for a reason.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Looking at [N3932](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3932.htm) I'm not sure the `_v` types should be in `experimental`, aren't they straight up additions to the library?

Comment: @user657267 that's what the proposal said, but that's not what got approved by the committee. They didn't get added to the C++ working paper, they went in the [Library Fundamentals TS](https://rawgit.com/cplusplus/fundamentals-ts/v1/fundamentals-ts.html) and so are in namespace `std::experimental`

Answer (score 9):

You may use the following:

```
namespace detail
{
    template <typename T> struct helper;

    template <typename T> struct helper<T*> { void operator() () const {std::cout << "pointer\n";} };
    template <typename T, std::size_t N> struct helper<T[N]> { void operator() ()const {std::cout << "array\n";} };
}


template <typename T>
void f(const T& )
{
    detail::helper<T>{}();
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/L6O8OV)

Comment: Thanks, your solution is probably the most "formal" one. Two comments: 1) the member function can be `static` (e.g. called `doit`) and 2) the specialization can be for a concrete type (in my case `char`), as in `struct helper<char const*>...` and `...size_t N> struct helper<char const[N]>...`

Comment: This seems prettier. It is more like pattern matching instead of `if` statement as in `std::enable_if`.

Answer (score 7):

I like using tag dispatching:

```
void foo(char const*, std::true_type /*is_pointer*/) {
  std::cout << "is pointer\n";
}
template<class T, size_t N>
void foo( T(&)[N], std::false_type /*is_pointer*/) {
  std::cout << "is array\n";
}
template<class X>
void foo( X&& x ) {
  foo( std::forward<X>(x), std::is_pointer<std::remove_reference_t<X>>{} );
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/38ace7fc9e74e668)

Comment: thanks, I guess the template `T` in the second function is not needed if one wants this only for char. `template<size_t N> void foo(char const(&)[N], std::false_type){...}`

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple solution that exploits the fact that [in C the value of an array is equal to its address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c) while this is generally not true for a pointer.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename P>
bool is_array(const P & p) {
  return &p == reinterpret_cast<const P*>(p);
}

int main() {
  int a[] = {1,2,3};
  int * p = a;

  std::cout << "a is " << (is_array(a) ? "array" : "pointer") << "\n";
  std::cout << "p is " << (is_array(p) ? "array" : "pointer") << "\n";
  std::cout << "\"hello\" is " << (is_array("hello") ? "array" : "pointer");
}
```

Note that while a pointer normally points to a location different from itself, this is not necessarily guaranteed; indeed you can easily fool the code by doing something like this:

```
//weird nasty pointer that looks like an array:
int * z = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&z);
```

However, since you are coding for fun, this can be a fun, basic, first approach.

Comment: The goal is to call a different overloaded function (meaning it must be resolved at compile-time) ... not sure if your `is_array` counts as that, even if you declare it `constexpr`

Comment: @MattMcNabb I agree with you, I was not sure if the goal was to create overloads or just tell an array from a pointer...

Comment: Nice (fun) runtime check and interesting fact. Indeed for the full example I had in mind a runtime check would have been sufficient because at the end most  of the function was the same for pointer and for arrays. In fact since the elements of one or the other are the same type the need for "genericity" of the function is only superficial. However, 1) compile time version seems appropriate still if the return type depends on the argument type (array or pointer). 2) you are using templates anyway in the function `is_array`.

Comment: @alfC I am using templates because this allows to check pointers of any type. If you just have one type you can easily remove the template.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it is as simple as this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
void foo(T const* t)
{
  cout << "pointer" << endl;
}

template<typename T, size_t n>
void foo(T(&)[n])
{
  cout << "array" << endl;
}

int main() {
  int a[5] = {0};
  int *p = a;
  foo(a);
  foo(p);
}
```

I don't get all the complication with `std::enable_if` and `std::true_type` and `std::is_pointer` and magic. If there's anything wrong with my approach please tell me.

Comment: It works as long as the arguments are non `const` (see @Thomas comment), which is one important case I wanted to cover (because of the constness of string literals).

Comment: @alfC My solution prints "array" when invoked on a string literal. Is that not what you expected? What is a case that my solution fails at?

Comment: Yes it does, but it is ambiguous if the array is `const`, I wanted to make it robust with respect to that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I too was wondering how to get around the compiler complaining about ambiguous overloads and fell across this.

This C++11 solution is similar in form to the dispatching answer but makes use of the variadic SFINAE trick instead (the compiler attempts the array version first). The "decltype" part allows different return types. If the required return type is fixed (e.g. "void" as per the OP) then it is not required.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template <typename T> T _thing1(T* x, ...) { cout << "Pointer, x=" << x << endl; return x[0]; }
template <typename T, unsigned N> T _thing1(T (&x)[N], int) { cout << "Array, x=" << x << ", N=" << N << endl; return x[0]; }
template <typename T> auto thing1(T&& x) -> decltype(_thing1(std::forward<T>(x), 0)) { _thing1(std::forward<T>(x), 0); }

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const int x0[20] = {101,2,3};
    cout << "return=" << thing1(x0) << endl;

    int x1[10] = {22};
    cout << "return=" << thing1(x1) << endl;

    float x2 = 3.141;
    cout << "return=" << thing1(&x2) << endl;

    const float x3 = 55.1;
    cout << "return=" << thing1(&x3) << endl;

}
```

Example output is:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 array_vs_ptr.cpp -o array_vs_ptr && ./array_vs_ptr
Array, x=0x22ca90, N=20
return=101
Array, x=0x22ca60, N=10
return=22
Pointer, x=0x22caec
return=3.141
Pointer, x=0x22cae8
return=55.1
```

Comment: Interesting solution. But it is an overkill because the example can be made to work without the ellipsis by adding `const&` to the first function. In which case reduces to the other solutions, `template <typename T> T _thing1(T* const& x) { cout << "Pointer, x=" << x << endl; return x[0]; }
template <typename T, unsigned N> T _thing1(T (&x)[N]) { cout << "Array, x=" << x << ", N=" << N << endl; return x[0]; }
template <typename T> auto thing1(T&& x) -> decltype(_thing1(std::forward<T>(x))) { return _thing1(std::forward<T>(x)); }`